# Jmeter Regular Expression To Extract A Number Having Varying Boundaries

Tags: regex, jmeter

I need to extract one number from a Jmeter response using  regular expression extractor as part of correlation.

Scenario is:

```
<span>Abc456ABC</span>
If I use <span>(.*?)</span>, then I will get "Abc456ABC".
If I use <span>Abc(.*?)ABC</span>, then I will get "456".
```

But the left and right boundary can vary.The input can be like:
Abcdef789ABCgh

I need only the number[In last case it is "789"]. Please suggest the suitable regular expression extractor.

Thanks In Advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<span>.*?([0-9]+).*?</span>
```

You can simply use this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uE6jQ1/11

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
<span>\D+(\d+)\D+</span>
```

See [RegEX DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pE5yY0/3)

Comment: This is working in one digit and <span>\w+(\d\d\d+)\w+</span> working for 3 digits. If there are more digits what should be the approach?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `<span>([\w]+)(\d+)([\w+])</span>`, It'll surely work

But use $2$ as template in regular expression extractor

([\w]+):it will capture all words and
(\d+): will take care of digits for you

Comment: Unfortunately, it wont work. `\w` includes `\d`.. so it will greedily match all the digits without giving enough to `\d+`.. Check my more appropriate answer :)

Comment: hi <span>([\w]+)(\d+)([\w]+)</span> is not getting correct values,retrieving only one digit, but  <span>([\D]+)(\d+)([\D]+)</span> does. But the $2$ mention was useful.